# Posting screen width using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, .post

Using this code

```
var sw = window.screen.width;
$.post("http://www.example.com/track.php", {result: sw
}, "html");
```

and $_SERVER['result']; in the server I'm trying to get the sreen width but it does not work. It is something wrong with the "result". I'm new in Javascript and jQuery...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Define "it does not work". Does $_SERVER['result'] have any value at all?
Some of the PHP would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SERVER` contains server variables, that is, things like the operating system, the referrer URL, paths to various folders on the server.

What you're looking for instead is either the `$_POST` array, the `$_GET` array, or the `$_REQUEST` array. I might be stating the obvious here, but here's what they contain:

- `$_POST` contains a list of all variables POSTed to the script.
- `$_GET` contains a list of all variables in the query string (eg: `someScript.php?x=1&y=2`)
- `$_REQUEST` contains a merge of `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` (usually in that order). I don't recommend using this: you should *know* the methods you're using to get variables into your script and use that array specifically.

In your case, you need to take a look at the `$_POST` array. It's always handy to run this once:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

This will show you everything posted to that page.

Comment: Are there any particular gotchas that we might fall into by using REQUEST or is it only about the consistency? Let me guess, what if POST and COOKIE contain variables with the same name, right?

Comment: yep. pretty much. If you're expecting a variable to come via post, then just check `$_POST`. Unexpected things generally lead to unexpected behaviour, so you gotta stamp it out asap.

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery $.post function sends a post request to the server, which means to access the value of "result", you need to get it from the $_POST superglobal.

Try $_POST['result'] instead of $_SERVER['result'].

These descriptions may help (source: http://www.nusphere.com/php/php_superglobals.htm):

- **$_POST**- The $_POST Superglobal represents data sent to the PHP
  script via HTTP POST. This is
  normally a form with a method of
  POST.
- **$_SERVER**- The $_SERVER Superglobal represents data available
  to a PHP script from the Web server
  itself (not what you're looking for)
- **$_REQUEST**- The $_REQUEST Superglobal is a combination of
  $_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIE (would
  work, but why search GET and COOKIE
  when you know the value is in POST?)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_REQUEST['result']`

> [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.
>
> [`$_REQUEST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)  is an associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

The correct way is to use `$_POST['result']`, as suggested by others here.

Comment: I didn't mean "don't use POST". From the question it sounded like he got confused between `SERVER` and `REQUEST` - that's why I went on to differentiate between them. Will edit in POST.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
echo $_POST['result'];
```